# command line: unmount a smb network drive

Tags: macos, terminal, mac, network, smb

We use Windows Server for my company network.

I do use Mac has client.  When I mount a network drive, I use the following command line:

```
osascript -e ‘mount volume “smb://myusername:mypassword@fileserver/department/its”'
```

everything works fine. I am a user administrator for my network, this is the reason why I guess I am able to mount the network drive in this way and everything works fine.

But my question is: **how do I unmount this network drive? What is the command line?**

thank you so much

Answer (score 35, accepted):

`umount` is the opposite of `mount`. You'll need to know the name of the mount point - that is, the name in /Volumes that corresponds to that network drive.

```
umount /Volumes/VolumeName
```

Per `man umount`, `umount` may fail for any number of reasons, and the recommend command is instead `diskutil`:

```
diskutil unmount /Volumes/VolumeName
```

Comment: And this is where the confusion comes for me :-) By using the command line that I posted in my original post, does the command line creates a mount point too? or it just mount the smb drive without creating the mount point? The reason why, I receive error message when I execute the following command: diskutil unmount /fileserver/department/its  I receive the following error: Unmount failed for /fileserver/department/its   or if I execute: unmount /fileserver/department/its   I receive: -bash: unmount: command not found

Comment: `/fileserver/department/its` is not a mount point. Unless otherwise specified with a specific mount point, everything is mounted under /Volumes. You will need to list the contents of that directory and find out what the corresponding name is to your network share. It's probably `its` since that's the last bit of the path from the server.

Comment: Done. Thank  you. The answer was: diskutil unmount its

Comment: The other thing is from your previous comment - note that the first command is `umount` _not_ `unmount` (notice that the proper command has no "n" in it). That's why you got "command not found" trying to run `unmount`. `diskutil` by contrast uses  the actual word (with the "n"): `diskutil unmount`.

Comment: There is also a force option
diskutil unmount force /Volumes/VolumeName